# zod schema not showing custom error message with number #10651

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

any ideas why I am unable to show a custom message on `number()` (`valueAsNumber: true`) inputs?

error messages are working correctly with `string()`?

```
const schema= z.object({
  companyName: z.string().min(2, { message: 'Please fill out this field' }),
  companyNumber: z.number().min(1, { message: 'Please fill out this field with numbers' }),
  email: z.string().email({ message: 'Please fill out this field' }),
  phone: z.number().min(2, { message: 'Please fill out this field with numbers' }),
});
```

```
 <TextInput
            label="Phone:
            name="phoneNumber"
            placeholder="xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
             {...(register('phone'), { valueAsNumber: true })}
             error={errors.phone?.message} // not showing?
          />
```

Comment: Have the same issue, no answers :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using shadcn-ui.

There was no issue with Zod, From the nested mess of elements, I deleted the `<FormMessage></FormMessage>` element, which caused the issue.

```
                    <FormItem>
                      <FormLabel>Number of similar compounds</FormLabel>
                      <FormControl>
                        <Input
                          type="number"
                          value=42
                        />
                      </FormControl>
                      <FormMessage></FormMessage> // !IMPORTANT
                    </FormItem>
```

Important to not miss the `<FormMessage></FormMessage>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, solved by overwriting the error map.

```js
z.object({
    name: z.string().trim().min(1, { message: customErrorMap.required }).max(255),
    categoryId: z.string().min(1, { message: customErrorMap.required }).max(255),
    level: z
  .number({
    errorMap: (issue, { defaultError }) => ({
      message: issue.code === 'invalid_type' ? customErrorMap.required : defaultError
    })
  })
  .int()
  .min(1),
  })
```